# Alterando plano de fundo do android via java

Tags: java, android

Estou com um aplicativo em mente, mas não sei como fazer a função principal dele.

Preciso alterar o plano de fundo da home sistema Android (não do aplicativo) através da aplicação.  Ex o usuaáio clica em um botão e este botão modifica a imagem no plano de fundo do sistema.

Alguém sabe se é possível alterar esse plano de fundo e como posso fazê-lo?

Comment: Olá tudo bem, não posso fazer para você mas posso te dar o caminho para você ESTUDAR, o android trabalha com intenções ou (INTENTS) utilize esse recurso para chamar a aplicação que faz isso.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao stackoverflow em português. Paulo tente ser mais especifico na sua dúvida. Assim como está a sua pergunta fica ampla de mais.

Comment: Eu discordo que a pergunta está ampla, talvez mal formulada, mas, pra mim, o que ele parece querer é só uma forma de mudar o plano de fundo da home do Android...

Comment: É isto mesmo @FelipeAvelar mudar através do app que vou desenvolver, vocês teriam algum material para me ajudar nisso?